# Unable to parse JSON with jQuery, returning [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I suspect my problem is due to the structure of my JSON string. It seem to have a JSON object within a JSON object.

This is the format of my JSON:

```
[
{"subject":{"title":"java","id":"1","desc":"Basic java programming"}, 
{"subject":{"title":"objective c","id":"2","desc":"Introduction to objective c"}
}
```

This is my jquery code:

```
var items = [];

    $.getJSON('theurl', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(key, subject) {
            alert(subject); //returning me "[object Object]"
            $('#tempresult').append('<p>'+ subject +'</p>'); //returning me "[object Object]"
        });
    });
```

Comment: That looks correct based on your object. What do you want instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have posted some malformed JSON. I'm going on the assumption that your elements are closed properly as:

```
[
  {"subject":{"title":"java","id":"1","desc":"Basic java programming"}},
  {"subject":{"title":"objective c","id":"2","desc":"Introduction to objective c"}}
]
```

It looks like you want `$('#tempresult').append('<p>'+ subject.subject.desc +'</p>');`

`data[0]` is this object:

```
{"subject":{"title":"java","id":"1","desc":"Basic java programming"}}
```

`data[1]` is this object:

```
{"subject":{"title":"objective c","id":"2","desc":"Introduction to objective c"}}
```

`data[0].subject` is this object:

```
{"title":"java","id":"1","desc":"Basic java programming"}
```

`data[0].subject.desc` is this:

```
"Basic java programming"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example JSON is a bit poorly formed (missing a `}`).

Otherwise, try this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, subject) {
    alert(subject.subject.title);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7xMJP/

Answer (score 1):

Your subject variable is a json object.
You have to specify the subject properties to get the value

`alert(subject.subject.id);
alert(subject.subject.title);
Alert(subject.subject.desc);`

Comment: i made the same mistake at first, but given his malformed JSON, i assume that the `title, id, desc` objects are wrapped in an obj with a key of `subject`: you'll need `subject.subject[...name...]` instead of just `subject[...name...]`

Comment: That's true, silly me. I'm on a mobile and i have limited screen. Thank you zzzzBov for noticing me.